# Terraform for_each loop aws_auth eks gets overwritten

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I am creating my very own EKS cluster and had some issues adding in roles via my namespace declared in locals dynamically
I am using the [terraform-aws-eks-auth Tag v1.0.0](https://github.com/aidanmelen/terraform-aws-eks-auth/tree/v1.0.0) to populate my IAM roles into the groups that i have created in terraform.

I expect that each.key variable would populate/append in the list of maps entries of map_roles but so far it doesn't do so. The end result in aws auth config map shows that it only contains AdminAccessRole, my_eks_admin_role, dev-kiwi-ingress-nginx_admin_role and dev-kiwi-ingress-nginx_readonly_role. The previous namespaces that was supposed to be dynamically created were overwritten.

Should I even use for_each in such case? How can I populate aws-auth dynamically by namespaces used, combined with 2 static entries.

I appreciate any advice or help!

```
locals {
  namespaces = [
    "${var.env}-devops",
    "${var.env}-devops-ingress-nginx",
    "${var.env}-shared",
    "${var.env}-shared-ingress-nginx",
    "${var.env}-pear",
    "${var.env}-pear-ingress-nginx",
    "${var.env}-apple",
    "${var.env}-apple-ingress-nginx",
    "${var.env}-banana",
    "${var.env}-banana-ingress-nginx",
    "${var.env}-kiwi",
    "${var.env}-kiwi-ingress-nginx"
  ]
}

module "eks_auth" {
  source = "./terraform-modules/terraform-aws-eks-auth-1.0.0"
  eks    = module.eks
  # Additional IAM roles to add to the aws-auth configmap.
  for_each = toset(local.namespaces)
  map_roles = [
    {
      rolearn  = "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/AdminAccessRole"
      username = "AdminAccessRole"
      groups   = ["system:masters"]
    },
    {
      rolearn  = "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/my-eks-admin-role"
      username = "my_eks_admin_role"
      groups   = ["system:masters"]
    },
    {
      rolearn  = aws_iam_role.eks_namespace_admin_roles[each.key].arn
      username = "${each.key}_admin_role"
      groups   = ["${each.key}:${each.key}_group"]
    },
    {
      rolearn  = aws_iam_role.eks_namespace_readonly_roles[each.key].arn
      username = "${each.key}_readonly_role"
      groups   = ["${each.key}:${each.key}_group"]
    }
  ]

  map_users = [
    {
      userarn  = "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/terraform-service-account"
      username = "terraform-service-account"
      groups   = ["system:masters"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Terraform v1.0.11
aws provider version = "~> 4.9.0"

Answer (score 2):

By adding the `for_each` in the level shown in the question, terraform will attempt to create multiple instances of the `eks_auth` module

In your case you need to apply the looping in the variable creation.
Also in order to not loop through the static definitions we use `concat` to merge the lists E.g.

```
  map_roles = concat( [ for index,value in toset(local.namespaces) :
   {
      rolearn  = aws_iam_role.eks_namespace_admin_roles[value].arn
      username = "${value}_admin_role"
      groups   = ["${value}:${value}_group"]
   },
   {
      rolearn  = aws_iam_role.eks_namespace_readonly_roles[value].arn
      username = "${value}_readonly_role"
      groups   = ["${value}:${value}_group"]
   }
  ], 
  [        
   {
       rolearn  = "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/AdminAccessRole"
       username = "AdminAccessRole"
       groups   = ["system:masters"]
   },
   {
      rolearn  = "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/my-eks-admin-role"
      username = "my_eks_admin_role"
      groups   = ["system:masters"]
   }
 ])
```

Comment: Thank You Tolis. It did not work as intended but the idea was there and I managed to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

With the help from Tolis, this is the answer to the issue.

It was still throwing out errors when tried to FOR loop a couple of map entries, so i split them up and concat multiple list instead.

```
module "eks_auth" {
  source = "./terraform-modules/terraform-aws-eks-auth-1.0.0"
  eks    = module.eks
  # Additional IAM roles to add to the aws-auth configmap.
  for_each = toset(local.namespaces)
  map_roles = concat(
    [
      for key in toset(local.namespaces) :
      {
        rolearn  = aws_iam_role.eks_namespace_admin_roles[key].arn
        username = "${key}_admin_role"
        groups   = ["${key}:${key}_group"]
      }
    ],
    [
      for key in toset(local.namespaces) :
      {
        rolearn  = aws_iam_role.eks_namespace_readonly_roles[key].arn
        username = "${key}_readonly_role"
        groups   = ["${key}:${key}_group"]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        rolearn  = "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/AdminAccessRole"
        username = "AdminAccessRole"
        groups   = ["system:masters"]
      },
      {
        rolearn  = "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/my-eks-admin-role"
        username = "my_eks_admin_role"
        groups   = ["system:masters"]
      }
  ])
  # Additional IAM users to add to the aws-auth configmap.
  map_users = [
  ]
}
```